# Implementing Smileys into my Chat Room MessageBox

Tags: c#, client, chat

I am wondering how could I implement emoticons in my chat room whilst I talk to other people/Friends.

Here is what I have to send my message out:(Chat Client's Form)

```
    private Image smiley = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\Smiles\\ConfusedSmiley.png");
    private void SendMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WriteMsg.Text != "")
        {
            int _index;
            _index = WriteMsg.Find(":S");
            if (_index != -1)
            {
                WriteMsg.Select(_index, ":S".Length);
                WriteMsg.InsertImage(smiley);
            }
              mConnection.SendMessage(".msg : " + WriteMsg.Text);
              WriteMsg.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

This is my connection with the Stream output:

```
    public void SendMessage(string Msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">>"+Msg);
        Outgoing.WriteLine(Msg);
        Outgoing.Flush();
    }
```

Now, as you can see, in my Chat Form's "SendMsg_Click", I have the type of image that should be sent when you type :S, well, all it does is send empty text, no image. I am currently using, Khendys.Controls "ExRichTextBox" to try and get the images working. Now, my other question is, do I need to add the same thing to the Server Client? If I only do it through the chat client, it would probably have to be in the server client as well is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to send the image (emotiocons) when they are used in the message. You should have the same set of images in client as well as server. Suppose you send from client :), then, in server side you need to replace the string with the local image (emoticon) same apply in the reverse.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought I had to do; I'm going to try it now.